# Uploading data from website to Azure Storage and Azure SQL

Tags: sql, azure, storage

I am to implement a service such the user can upload files to azure storage, and also store the meta data in a azure sql database.

Lets say the user want to upload 1gb of data, is it then needed to be send to the webservice first and then from service to azure storage?  Is there a way to initiate the upload and then the user sends the data directly to the server with azure storage?

I think i read something like that but cant find it now and not sure what to search for on google.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible but you'll need to use a client side technology which can talk to the REST API, like Silverlight for example. Steve Marx did a series of blog posts explaining how you can leverage Silverlight and the REST API to upload files to blob storage (even very large files): [Uploading Windows Azure Blobs from Silverlight – Part 3: Handling Big Files by Using the Block APIs](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/uploading-windows-azure-blobs-from-silverlight-part-3-handling-big-files-by-using-the-block-apis). And a Silverlight control is very easy to integrate in an existing website.

Comment: If its just talking to a rest api, why cant i do so with http calls?

Comment: What about authentication, can every user then just upload a file to the store? guessing a user should first be allowed to upload a file before they can